# Custom Fields Query Vars and Rewrite not working

Tags: rewrite-rules, query-variable

i have a problem with query vars and rewrite rules. 
I have 
- a page called "luoghi"
- one custom field called "test_city"
- a query var called "city"

Into "luoghi" page i did the query with custom fields and everything works. If i reach:

```
http://localhost/wptest/luoghi/?city=milano
```

I see the list of posts filtered by custom field. I'm trying to convert ?city=milano to /milano/ with no success. These are the functions:

```
function myplugin_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'city';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'myplugin_register_query_vars' );


add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
function myplugin_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%city%', '([^&]+)' );
}

add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
function myplugin_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^luoghi/city/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=luoghi&city=$matches[1]','top' );
}
```

Query monitor doesn't help a lot:
[image]

Comment: when you go to this URL, do you see what you excepted ? http://localhost/wptest/index.php?pagename=luoghi&city=milano

Comment: I see the right query. The problem is that rewrite is not working. Everything else is okay. If i reach http://localhost/wptest/luoghi/city/milano/ it works, the problem is that it's not rewriting arguments

Comment: the rewrite works because you see "pagename=luoghi&city=milano" in the query monitor. and I try your code and it's works without modification when I go to URL `http://server/luoghi/city/milano/`

Comment: yes but it doesn't rewrite pagename=luoghi&city=milano to /luoghi/city/milano automatically. That's my problem. I need to rewrite that url when i visit it